# Flask cannot find templates folder because it is working from a stale root directory

Tags: flask

Flask cannot find my templates directory. I had a working program at C:\old\path\HerokuApp, with everything set up and working correctly.

Then I deleted everything in C:\old\path\HerokuApp, so it's empty now, and I put all the files in C:\new\path\HerokuApp (technically, I cloned from github into the new path).

Now, when I go to http://localhost:5000, I get a jinja stacktrace error, which contains the following line:

```
File "C:/old/path/HerokuApp/launcher.py", line 14, in home
```

But as I said, this file doesn't exist any more!

**My question:** How can I get Flask to refresh its working directory?

I have tried launching the app in three different ways, all of which I thought would run it from the root directory of the project:

(1) using python:

```
C:\new\path\HerokuApp>"C:\path\to\python.exe" launcher.py
```

(2) using flask:

```
set FLASK_APP=launcher.py
C:\new\path\HerokuApp>"C:\path\to\flask.exe" run
```

(3) using spyder:

```
runfile('C:/new/path/HerokuApp/launcher.py', wdir='C:/new/path/HerokuApp')
```

Comment: Are you sure the absolute path to the old location isn't hardcoded somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured it out. Previously, I had been using Spyder to run the app, but restarting the kernel or closing Spyder doesn't cleanly kill it ... the Windows Task Manager showed that there will still a python process running. Killing *that* finally stopped the localhost:5000 port being served. After doing this I was able to launch my app from the new path.

The takeaway for me is not to use Spyder to launch Flask apps: it offers no way to stop the server (as of version 3.1.4). In contrast, launching the app using either python or flask -- (1) and (2) in my question -- explicitly gives you an option to do so by pressing ctrl-C.